# How to call mysql date_format function in JPQL

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I'm developing a webservice using `eclipseLink 2.4.1`, `JPA 2.0.1` and other supporting tools. I have created a table which has a column of date type. I want to get records of a particular date. I'm using date_format of mysql and getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing[select o from Clients o  where FUNCTION('date_format',{o.effectiveStartDate},{d,'dd-mm-yyyy'})='27-05-2014']
[90, 111] The JDBC escape format does not start with either 'd', 't' or 'ts'.
[110, 110] The JDBC escape format is missing the close quote.
```

Even I tried to call date_format  directly as :

```
Select o from Clients o  where date_format(o.effectiveStartDate '%d-%m-%Y'})='27-05-2014'
```

Then I get syntax error parsing. `invalid token [(]`.

I tried with namedQuery also but didn't get success.

How to call such function JPQL.

Comment: Hi, mehdi lotfi. Thanks for editing and making it more readable. I am new and how can i do such formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "{o.effectiveStartDate}" trying to do ? Remove the curly brackets or it will try to interpret that as a JDBC escape syntax date (which it isn't).

JPA 2.1 'FUNCTION' syntax would be

```
FUNCTION("date_format", o.effectiveStartDate, "the_date_format")
```

where "the_date_format" matches what MySQL accepts for its second arg as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

That of course requires you to use a JPA2.1 compliant implementation; your implementation may have some other vendor-specific FUNC or otherwise which is not portable and I've no time for when there's a standard variant that should do what you need

Comment: effectiveStartDate is a column in table and i want its value. can you give me one example how to call date_format function in JPQL??

Comment: tried in simple format but it was giving error so tried with JDBC object.

Comment: tried as following :<br> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
<br>Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [ select o from Client o  where  o.effectiveStartDate={d,'27-05-2014'} ]. 
<br>[90, 105] The JDBC escape format does not start with either 'd', 't' or 'ts'.
<br> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1512)

Comment: FUNCTION is a feature of JPA 2.1. You don't seem to be using that.

Comment: yeah,it is. if i call date_format in dynamic query then it gives error like invalid token[(].Any link of example for date_format function?

Comment: Thanks for your help. i was passing wrong format.There was no need of {}.